# table.put_item w/ Partition and Sort Key in Python (Lambda to DynamoDB)

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am altering a Lambda function (written in Python) that puts an item into a DynamoDB table. I have no issues when using the function to write to a DDB table with only a primary key, but get the following error after aligning attribute names and writing to a table with a *partition* and *sort* key:

An error occurred (`ValidationException`) when calling the `PutItem` operation:

> One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key ID

Here is my function:

```
# import the json utility package since we will be working with a JSON object
import json
# import the AWS SDK (for Python the package name is boto3)
import boto3
# import two packages to help us with dates and date formatting
from time import gmtime, strftime

# create a DynamoDB object using the AWS SDK
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
# use the DynamoDB object to select our table
table = dynamodb.Table('PSCartTracking')
# store the current time in a human readable format in a variable
now = strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())

# define the handler function that the Lambda service will use as an entry point
def lambda_handler(event, context):
# extract values from the event object we got from the Lambda service and store in a variable
    login = event['login']
    computer = event['computer']
    timestamp = event['timestamp']
# write name and time to the DynamoDB table using the object we instantiated and save response in a variable
    response = table.put_item(
        Item={
            'ID': computer,
            'Timestamp': timestamp,
            'Login': login
            })
# return a properly formatted JSON object
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(login + ' checked out ' + computer + ' on ' + now)
    }
```

Keys for Table:

```
Partition key
ID (String)
Sort key
Timestamp (String)
```

I've been trying to read documentation to figure out what about my formatting might be preventing it from recognizing the sort key, but I'm pretty positive that is the part of the composite it is not seeing.

Comment: What exactly is `event['timestamp']`?

Comment: Before I was using now as the time stamp in the function, but thought I could pass through the JSON attribute similarly to the working variables (computer and login). So I created an event that inherits the JSON time stamp from the object and just grabbed the time prior to the API call. Is there a different way I can pass this attribute?